# Azure web jobs VS azure batch VS worker roles

Tags: azure, web-worker, azure-webjobs, azure-batch

What are the pros/cons to decide on the approach for data processing on top of Azure? We see Azure web jobs, Azure batch and Azure worker roles, but literally unsure on pros/cons of each choice, especially on scalability and cost.

Assuming e have data processing from azure queue.
From 1-5 data item per day, to 500 items per minute. Each item requires custom processing (bits if C# logic) something in between 5 second to 5 minutes depending on the nature of the data.

Having such payload, how we decide on web jobs, Azure batch or workers?
What would be the major criterias to decide?

Comment: Webjobs share the resources used by your web role, so are useful for tasks that won't significantly impact on web role performance. Worker roles are completely separate - so great for heavy lifting -  but add additional complexity and cost. Checkout the Azure Friday or Cloud 9 series - there is lots of information there.

Answer (score 2):

I would say for sure Web jobs would not be appropriate. it is more about running complimentary tasks for your website. If you put high processing job it can impact your website performance.

You can choose between Azure Batch Jobs and Worker Roles, the main distinguishing factor would be if you want to process your tasks in parallel then Azure Batch Jobs would suite more, you can also re-size the pool at runtime.

If you want to monitor the queue and process the request at regular interval, think about worker role.